# Installing AWS CLI Version 2 in GitLab-Runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, aws-cli, gitlab-ci-runner

In-order to deploy my `Spring-Boot` application into `AWS ECS`, I have the need of installing `AWS CLI Version 2` into my `GitLab-Runner` which is running in `AWS EC2` Linux based `AMI`. I will add below the scripts and stage used to install `AWS CLI version 2`.

This is the deploy stage and the image used.

```
deploy:
  image: alpine:3.11
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - demo-ci
  script:
```

Below I mentioned the script used to install `AWS CLI Version 2` within the above mentioned stage.

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
./aws/install
aws --version
```

When I am running the script, I get the following issue.

```
$ ./aws/install
./aws/install: line 78: /builds/sl-psf/SpringDemoECS/aws/dist/aws: not found
You can now run: /usr/local/bin/aws --version
$ aws --version
/bin/sh: eval: line 130: aws: not found
```

Even though it is mentioned to try `/usr/local/bin/aws --version`, it doesn't work either.

However there is a workaround and it solved the issue and I will put the code below for that.

```
variables:
  REGION: "us-east-2"
  REPOSITORY_URL: "############.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
  IMAGE_TAG: "demo-app:0.1"
  GLIBC_VER: "2.31-r0"


[......]

docker-deploy:
  image: alpine:3.11
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip binutils curl
    - curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub
    - curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk
    - curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk
    - curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VER}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk
    - apk add --no-cache glibc-${GLIBC_VER}.apk glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VER}.apk glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VER}.apk
    - /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
    - curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip
    - unzip awscliv2.zip
    - aws/install
    - rm -rf awscliv2.zip aws /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/aws_completer /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/awscli/data/ac.index /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/*/dist/awscli/examples glibc-*.apk
    - apk --no-cache del binutils curl
    - rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
    - aws --version
```

I don't think this is the optimal way to install `AWS CLI Version 2`. It was pretty difficult to do this task and there are various ways suggested. I think that this is a common issue lots of people might have faced. My question is that is there a better way to achieve this or if so then what would be the way?

Comment: once you installed `pip3`, what about `pip3 install awscliv2` ?

Comment: Can you change the image you're using for that job from `alpine:3.11` to `amazon/aws-cli`?  Unless you need functionality in Alpine specifically, using the aws-cli image will have `aws` available for you without any extra work.

Comment: @NicolasPepinster I will try it and let you know. thanks!

Comment: @AdamMarshall I will change the image and try. thanks!